# Select from zsh completion menu by number

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, zsh-completion

I discovered this little navigation trick the other day, which allows me to trigger menu completions by number when I enter 'cd -'

```
~ cd -
0 -- ~/home
1 -- ~/home/stuff
2 -- ~/downloads
3 -- ~/wallpaper
```

Shell scripting syntax still reads like a foreign language to me, but to get this functionality my directory stack history is piped into the function below.

```
DIRSTACKSIZE=9
DIRSTACKFILE=~/.zdirs

if [[ -f $DIRSTACKFILE ]] && [[ $#dirstack -eq 0 ]]; 
   then dirstack=( ${(f)"$(< $DIRSTACKFILE)"} )
   [[ -d $dirstack[1] ]] && cd $dirstack[1] && cd $OLDPWD
fi
  chpwd() {
  print -l $PWD ${(u)dirstack} >$DIRSTACKFILE
```

}

The magical part is being able to choose from the list by number, but I have come to learn that this is probably
because the functionality for navigation by number is baked in to the 'cd -' command.  Still, I'd like to use this everywhere.

Any tips writing a wrapper function (or something like that, I guess) for the completion menu that pipes in completions from the menu when it is triggered
and displays them in a numbered list where those numbers select the corresponding element?

I've gotten started reading the manual and what not, but everything remains rather opaque. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First off, the code snippet you show has nothing to do with completion. Instead, what it does is to record the directory stack to a file in order to preserve it between zsh sessions. (Personally, I'm not even sure this is a good idea.)

A good place to start investigating zsh completions is the `_complete_help` ZLE widget. This is bound by default to `^Xh` in zsh's `viins` (vi insert) keyboard map, but is unbound by default in the `emacs` keymap. If you want to use it in the `emacs` keymap (the default for many people), you have to bind it:

```
bindkey -M emacs "^Xh" _complete_help
```

Now you can type `cd -` (or `cd +`) and follow it by <kbd>CTRL-X</kbd><kbd>h</kbd> instead of <kbd>TAB</kbd>. You should see the following output:

```
tags in context :completion::complete:cd::
    directory-stack  (_directory_stack _cd)
```

(At this point I'll admit we're getting close to the limits of my knowledge of the zsh completion system.)

Now you can see the completer functions for the `directory-stack` tag in this particular context. The one you're probably interested in is `_directory_stack`, and you can see the content of that function with:

```
functions _directory_stack
```

…which is where those leading numbers are actually generated.

Arguably it's *possible* to write similar completion functions for other completion contexts, and apply the using `zstyle`. However, this is non-trivial completion magic, and beyond anything I have attempted